# Why Drive.Builder cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing an Android app in Eclipse, and I believe I have integrated all of the necessary `.jar` files and also `google_play_services` into my project and added them to my build path.  I am pretty sure I have imported every necessary library as well, but I still get a

> ```
> Drive.Builder cannot be resolved to a type
> ```

error.  There has got to be a reason why this message continues to show up. Can someone help me figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your import. You need `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive` rather than `com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive`.